# iOS SwiftUI: Light/Dark color doesn't change

Tags: ios, swiftui

I've made a custom view made by a path filled with a custom color.

This is the color:

[image]

And as you can see it already conforms to light and dark appearance.

**But still, when I select the dark theme the color stays black**.
Do you know if I have to do some configuration for custom view and path?

This is the body of my custom view (I can't provide the fully path because of the Copyright)

```
struct ASymbol : View {
    let symbolColor: Color

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Path { path in
                let side = min(geometry.size.width, geometry.size.height)
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: side * 0.92, y: side * 0.79))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: side * 0.5, y: 0))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: side))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: side, y: side))
                ...
                path.closeSubpath()

        }
        .fill(self.symbolColor)
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit:

**I've just noticed that this not work even if I apply my custom color to a text.**

Comment: This issue was fixed with Xcode 11 beta 3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56534286/3815069