# Xcode 11 -- SwiftUI's dark mode setup

Tags: swiftui, xcode11, ios13

Okay.  I know this shouldn't be rocket science.  I can't seem to get dark mode working and I've read the documentation a few times.  Hoping someone can pick out what I'm missing.

I have an named color in the asset catalog.[image]

I set my plist mode to be in dark mode for easier testing.
[image]

My content view looks like this:

```
struct ContentView : View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Hello World")
        Text("Yo yo yo")
            .color(Color("darkModeColor"))
    }

}
```

}

No matter what I do, the color is ALWAYS of the "Any" appearance when it should be taking on the cyan color.

[image]

I know dark mode itself works because all the system semantic colors provide by apple are working just fine as you can see the "Hello World" text changed to white.

Any ideas what I'm missing or is anyone else running into this issue with Xcode 11 Beta 1?

Comment: This issue was fixed with Xcode 11 beta 3 :]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably a bug in this beta release of Xcode 11. I tried the dark mode feature in a UIKit application and it is working perfectly using `UIColor` but the same color wouldn’t work using `Color` in SwiftUI. Hopefully this will be fixed in the next releases.

---

**Update**: This issue was fixed with **Xcode 11 beta 3**.

Comment: agreed.  just helps to run it by other developers rather than pulling my hair out!

Comment: this is still happening in beta 2, isn't it?

Comment: @Miotz  Yes it's not fixed yet.

Answer (score 4):

A working (but quite verbose) solution we can use to overcome this current limitation is to extend Color with methods parameterised with the current color scheme as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

extension Color {

    static let lightBackgroundColor = Color(white: 1.0)

    static let darkBackgroundColor = Color(white: 0.0)

    static func backgroundColor(for colorScheme: ColorScheme) -> Color {
        if colorScheme == .dark {
            return darkBackgroundColor
        } else {
            return lightBackgroundColor
        }
    }
}
```

And in the views where you need to access these colors you would add an environment property for the color scheme and use it to retrieve the dynamic color:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ColoredView : View {

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().fill(Color.backgroundColor(for: self.colorScheme))
    }
}
```

These colours defined in code work for Xcode previews as well as the simulator.

Comment: If we have to use color like this, then what is meaning of color template in assets. your question is not giving answer for the question, instead it is giving alternative manual way...

Comment: That is all very fine and dandy but as others pointed out, color template in assets do not work in the current beta. I am simply providing a working alternative.

Comment: Works for me - at least as a temporary workaround. I wanted semantic borders to a few view all contained in my root `ContentView`. I appreciate the tip.

Answer (score -2):

You can change color scheme in your preview

```swift
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
    }
}
```

**upd**: and you can create any previews for light and dark modes

```swift
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
            ContentView().environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working with colors, please read question properly, try the same thing and then answer.